# Get contents from <link> (not <a>) tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm trying to get contents of the link tag. So with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css">
```

**I want the contents of the file some.css in a string.**

Tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].firstChild.nodeValue; // fails
document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].hasChildNodes(); // false
```

Any ideas? I don't want to use the styleSheet method (which only works in FF anyway) because it will strip out stuff like -moz-border-radius and such.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should make an ajax call.

Comment: The `<link>` element is empty, so it can't have any child nodes. I don't really get what you mean by contents though, do you mean the contents of that file?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without document.styleSheets. Btw, that works in most of the browsers, but there are incompatibilities: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html

Comment: I was thinking the AJAX call as well or have your server-side code to do something like `file_get_contents()` (for PHP) then have it added to the JavaScript var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Daniel A. White is correct.  Your best bet is to get the href of the stylesheet, then load the content via Ajax and parse it.

What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Just parsing the style sheet mostly. AJAX is a no go because it doesn't work locally (file:///) correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the contents of a file with only javascript. You'll need an ajax request to the server which opens the file and returns its contents.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to access the file via an ajax request.

So, with jQuery, something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some.css",
  success: function(){
    //do something
  }
});
```

More details here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Note: this only works if the file making the request is on the same server as the file requested.

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules offer a [special API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/ecma-script-binding.html), but nothing like innerHTML.

This is as close as it gets:

```
var result = '';
var st = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
for (var i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
    result += st[i].cssText;
}
console.log(result);
```

However, this will not respect whitespace, comments, erroneous rules, ...

And as usual, this is subject to Same Origin Policy.